# Sorting in particular manner rather than Ascending or descending

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript sort method. I want to sort the doc_requirement  key of items in order 1,4,3,0
But the order I am getting is 4,3,1,0 .
How to achieve a particular order rather than sorting in ascending or descending manner?

```
var items = [
  { doc_requirement :4},
  { doc_requirement: 3 },
  { doc_requirement:3  },
  {doc_requirement: 0 },
  { doc_requirement: 1 },
  { doc_requirement: 3 }
];

items.sort(function(firstDoc, secondDoc) {
if(firstDoc.doc_requirement < secondDoc.doc_requirement){
                        return true;
                    } else if(firstDoc.doc_requirement == secondDoc.doc_requirement){
                        return true;
                    } else{
                        return false;
                    }
});
```

Output expected

```
var items =[ { doc_requirement: 1 },
      { doc_requirement: 4 },
      { doc_requirement: 3 },
      { doc_requirement: 3 },
      { doc_requirement: 3 },
      { doc_requirement: 0 } ]
```

Comment: Read the [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Parameters) API

Comment: what do you mean by 1,4,3,0? Always 1 first and then the highest number or? Elaborate..!

Comment: Sort function should return numbers not boolean.

Comment: Check the output @dotTutorials

Comment: You should elaborate more @AryanKanwar. How would you order an object with `doc_requirement = 2`? Is the order `1,N,N-1,N-2...5,4,3,2,0` what you want?

Comment: The item object key (doc_requirment) will only contain  values as 1,4,0,3 @Oneiros

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sort function should return integers, not booleans (Source: [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Parameters)). It should look like this:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

In your case, you could use this:

```
function compare(a, b) {
   var order = [1, 4, 3, 0];
   var i1 = order.indexOf(a.doc_requirement);
   var i2 = order.indexOf(b.doc_requirement);
   return i1 - i2;
}
```